# How to put sequential numbers into lists from a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list numbers say,

`[1,2,3,6,8,9,10,11]`

First, I want to get the sum of the differences (step size) between the numbers `(n, n+1)` in the list.

Second, if a set of consecutive numbers having a difference of 1 between them, put them in a list, i.e. there are two such lists in this example,

`[1,2,3]`

`[8,9,10,11]`

and then put the rest numbers in another list, i.e. there is only one such list in the example,

`[6]`.

Third, get the lists with the max/min sizes from the sequential lists, i.e. `[1,2,3]`, `[8,9,10,11]` in this example, the max list is,

`[8,9,10,11]`

min list is

`[1,2,3]`.

What's the best way to implement this?

Comment: Considering all your requirements, you should at least have tried something

Comment: What have you tried ? Also why is `4` missing from the `[1, 2, 3]` list?

Comment: Take a look at `itertools.groupby`.

Comment: @PM2Ring `groupby` seems can only return consecutive keys, which doesn't really fit in here

Comment: @daiyue Should the last min result be `[1,2,3]`?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye yes, it should be `[1,2,3]` as `min([1,2,3], [8,9,10,11])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> First, I want to get the sum of the differences (step size) between
>   the numbers `(n, n+1)` in the list.

Use `sum` on the successive differences of elements in the list:

```
>>> sum(lst[i] - x for i, x in enumerate(lst[:-1], start=1))
10
```

---

> Second, if a set of consecutive numbers having a difference of 1 between them, put them in a list, i.e. there are two such lists in
>   this example, and then put the rest numbers in another list, i.e.
>   there is only one such list in the example,

[`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) does this by grouping on the difference of each element on a reference [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) object:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby, count
>>> c = count()    
>>> result = [list(g) for i, g in groupby(lst, key=lambda x: x-next(c))]
>>> result
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [6], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
```

---

> Third, get the lists with the max/min sizes from above

`max` and `min` with the *key function* as `sum`:

```
>>> max(result, key=sum)
[8, 9, 10, 11]
>>> min(result, key=sum)
[6] #??? shouldn't this be [6]
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, I have modified the OP that I need to get max/min sizes from sequential lists, i.e. `[1,2,3]`,`[8,9,10,11]`.

Comment: I think your result is wrong because `4` is missing from the first list

Comment: yes, you are right, I made a mistake in the OP, and I have corrected it. My thinking is how can I put sequential lists (i.e. `[1,2,3]`,`[8,9,10,11]`) in one list, and non-sequential list (i.e. `[6]`) in a separated list?

Comment: Use a list comprehension and apply a filter `if len(sublist) == 1` to get non sequential items and `if len(sublist) != 1` to get sequential ones

Comment: The thing is the non-sequential list could have more than one element, e.g. for a list `[1,2,3,6,8,9,10,11,13]`, how to get a list that contains two sequential lists (i.e. `[[1,2,3],[8,9,10,11]]`) and a separated non-sequencial list(i.e. `[6,13]`) in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you've already got the answer to this (given the missing 4 from your answers) as the first thing I naively tried produced that answer. (That and/or it reads like a homework question)

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,6,8,9,10,11]
>>> sum([a[x+1] - a[x] for x in range(len(a)-1)])
10
>>> [a[x] for x in range(len(a)-1) if abs(a[x] - a[x+1]) ==1]
[1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10]
```

Alternatively, try :

```
a=[1,2,3,6,8,9,10,11]
sets = []
cur_set = set()
total_diff = 0
for index in range(len(a)-1):
    total_diff += a[index +1] - a[index]
    if a[index +1] - a[index] == 1:
        cur_set = cur_set | set([ a[index +1], a[index]])
    else:
        if len(cur_set) > 0:
            sets.append(cur_set)
        cur_set = set()

if len(cur_set) > 0:
    sets.append(cur_set)

all_seq_nos = set()
for seq_set in sets:
    all_seq_nos = all_seq_nos | seq_set
non_seq_set = set(a) - all_seq_nos

print("Sum of differences is {0:d}".format(total_diff))

print("sets of sequential numbers are :")
for seq_set in sets:
    print(sorted(list(seq_set)))

print("set of non-sequential numbers is :")
print(sorted(list(non_seq_set)))

big_set=max(sets, key=sum)
sml_set=min(sets, key=sum)
print ("Biggest set of sequential numbers is :")
print (sorted(list(big_set)))
print ("Smallest set of sequential numbers is :")
print (sorted(list(sml_set)))
```

Which will produce the output :

```
Sum of differences is 10
sets of sequential numbers are :
[1, 2, 3]
[8, 9, 10, 11]
set of non-sequential numbers is :
[6]
Biggest set of sequential numbers is :
[8, 9, 10, 11]
Smallest set of sequential numbers is :
[1, 2, 3]
```

Hopefully that all helps ;-)

Comment: I think for the second part of your answer, OP wanted to split the list into smaller list where each number is going up by 1. Example does not match what you have.

Comment: @MooingRawr: Hopefully post edit the second block of code is closer to what you/the OP is after